# Terragrunt v0.14.9, Terraform v0.11.7 reading AWS VPC ID from second environment

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terragrunt

I have used Terragrunt to orchestrate the creation of a non-default AWS VPC.
I've got S3/DynamoDB state mgmt, and the VPC code is a module. I have the 'VPC environment' `terraform.tfvars` code checked into a second repo as per the `terragrunt` [README.md](https://github.com/gruntwork-io/terragrunt).

I created a second module which will eventually create hosts in this VPC but for now just aims to output its ID.  I have created a separate 'hosts environment' / `terraform.tfvars` for the instantiation of this module.

1. I run `terragrunt apply` in the VPC environment directory - VPC created
2. I run `terragrunt apply` a second time in the hosts environment directory - output directive doesn't work (no error, but incorrect, see below).

This is a precursor to one day running a `terragrunt apply-all` in the parent directory of the VPC/hosts environment directories; my reading of the docs suggest using a `terraform_remote_state` data source to expose the VPC ID, so I specified access like this in the `data.tf` file of the hosts *module*:

```
data "terraform_remote_state" "vpc" {
    backend = "s3"
    config {
        bucket  = "myBucket"
        key     = "keyToMy/vpcEnvironment.tfstate"
        region  = "stateRegion"
    }
}
```

Then, in the hosts *module* `outputs.tf`, I specified an output to check assignment:

```
output "mon_vpc" {
    value = "${data.terraform_remote_state.vpc.id}"
}
```

When I run (2) above, it exits with:

> Apply complete! Resources: 0 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed.
>
> Outputs:
>
> mon_vpc = 2018-06-02 23:14:42.958848954 +0000 UTC

Questions:

1. I'm going wrong setting up the code so that the hosts *environment* is configured to correctly acquire the VPC ID from the already-existing VPC (terraform state file) - any advice on what to change here would be appreciated.
2. It does look like I've managed to acquire the date of when the VPC was created rather than its ID, which given the code is perplexing - anyone know why?

I'm not using community modules - all hand rolled.

EDIT: In response to Brandon Miller, here is a bit more.  In my VPC module, I have an outputs.tf containing among other outputs:

```
output "aws_vpc.mv.id-op" {
    value = "${aws_vpc.mv.id}"
}
```

and the vpc.tf contains

```
resource "aws_vpc" "mv" {
    cidr_block = "${var.vpcCidr}"
    enable_dns_support = true
    enable_dns_hostnames = true
    tags = {
        Name = "mv-vpc-${var.aws_region}"
    }
}
```

As this cfg results in a vpc being created, and as most of the parameters are `<computed>`, I assumed state would contain sufficient data for other modules to refer to by consulting state (I assumed at first that terraform used the AWS API for this under the bonnet, rather than consulting a different state key).

EDIT 2: Read all of @brendan-miller's answer and following comments first.
Use of periods causes a problem as it confuses terraform (see Brendan's answer for the specification format below):

```
Error: output 'mon_vpc': unknown resource 'data.aws_vpc.mv-ds' referenced in variable data.aws_vpc.mv-ds.vpc.id
```

Comment: How are you declaring the output for your vpc in the remote state?

Comment: @brandon-miller I've edited the post to reflect my declarations.  Let me know if that answers your question.

Comment: thanks, hopefully my helps clear things up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You named your output `aws_vpc.mv.id-op` but when you retrieve it you are retrieving just `id`. You could try

```
data.terraform_remote_state.vpc.aws_vpc.mv.id
```

but im not sure if Terraform will complain about the additional `.`. However the format should always be

```
data.terraform_remote_state.<name of the remote state module>.<name of the output>
```

You mentioned wanting to be able to get this info with the AWS API. That is also possible by using the [`aws_vpc`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/d/vpc.html) data source. Their example uses id, but you can also use any tag you used on your vpc.

Like this:

```
data "aws_vpc" "default" {
  filter {
    name   = "tag:Name"
    values = ["example-vpc-name"]
  }
}
```

Then you can use this for the id

```
${data.aws_vpc.default.id}
```

In addition this retrieves all tags set, for example:

```
${data.aws_vpc.default.tags.Name}
```

And the cidr block

```
${data.aws_vpc.default.cidr_block}
```

As well as some other info. This can be very useful for storing and retrieving things about your VPC.

Comment: @brendan-miller yes I thought the periods might cause issue, but it was the use of the `aws_vpc` `data source` filter that won it. Chrs!

Comment: Good to know that the periods dont cause a problem!

Comment: No they do, sorry I should have tested both separately. See my EDIT2.